# Eclipse - how to set javadoc warnings only to specific folders, not the whole project

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings, javadoc

Some of my colleagues lack discipline and not always write documentation of their classes(not always = never). I was trying to force them to write documentation by setting project warnings for missing comment javadocs. We got two source folders 'src' and 'tests' - obviously not all @Test methods needs documentation and this warning there is redundant. But now all undocumented tests got these annoying warnings, the project got hundreds of warnings and I'm afraid that some real dangerous warnings will be missed(because there are hundreds of useless ones).

How to set warnings only on the 'src' folder, and ignore the warnings on 'tests' folder?

Comment: Just saw @SuppressWarnings("javadoc") (facepalm)

Comment: Besides that, I always set the "Problems" view to only show "resource and its children". In that way you will still see all warnings if you select the root folder of the project (in the package viewer). If you however click on any source folder, it will only show the errors/warnings for that specific one.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid there is no setting to disable missing javadoc validation strictly for Test classes/methods. There even was a suggestion posted on Eclipse bugzilla [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=108208) but eventually it came to an dead end.

The only, nonelegant way of solving this issue is by annotating those test methods with `@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")` annotation.

Comment: What a pity. The classes are outo-generated in my case, so annotationg them is no option.