# How do I prevent R.java from being javadoc validated in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, validation, javadoc

I have an Android project in Eclipse.

It has an automatically generated file called R.java. It is not javadoc compliant.

I would like to excuse this file from javadoc validation tests when building.

Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

Thanks

**EDIT: HALF SOLUTION**

IT appears to be impossible...

[Eclipse - how to set javadoc warnings only to specific folders, not the whole project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268165/eclipse-how-to-set-javadoc-warnings-only-to-specific-folders-not-the-whole-pr)

I'm surprised this is feature that hasn't been implemented in a newer version of Eclipse?

The best way to remove the errors is to go Window/Preferences/Java/Compiler/Javadoc and change to "Ignore" as appropriate. Doesn't help code quality but definitely keeps you sane!

Another suggestion would be to just turn on JavaDoc validation in intervals and simply hide/group errors by source file in "Problem Settings" in Eclipse. Messy.

Comment: What validator is checking for Javadoc compliance?

Comment: Sorry, I don't entirely understand the question. I think the answer you are looking for is: the validator under Window/Preferences/Compiler/Javadoc

Answer (score 0):

The 'gen' directory could be excluded when generate javadoc.

Comment: I could but this would not prevent/remove the 918 errors that I have at the moment! Javadoc can be generated perfectly well. It is the validation that is the issue.

Comment: Then, seems applying filters in 'Problem' pane may be a solution.